# iPhone: How to get VoiceOver to recognize standard gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

Right now I have some very simple code setup to recognize gestures. However, when my device has VoiceOver enabled and I try to use the double-tap gesture feature (to pass the gesture through voiceOver into the app), it doesn't seem to recognize the gesture.

To clarify more:
Normally, if you are using an app with voiceover enabled and the app has some gesture recognition, you can double-tap and hold for a second and voiceover will play a tone. You can then perform the gesture and it will be passed through voiceover into the app.  My problem is that when I double-tap and hold, voiceover doesn't play the tone.

So I am wondering if there is something I have to include in my code to notify voiceover that my app will be using gesture, or something to that effect.

code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Swipe Left
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];

swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
[swipeLeft release];

// Swipe Right
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];

swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
[swipeRight release];
}


- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{

CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"Swipe left started at (%f,%f)",location.x,location.y);
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, @"Swipe Left");
}

- (void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{

CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"Swipe right started at (%f,%f)",location.x,location.y);
}
```

Comment: I experience the same problem and cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that VoiceOver doesn't play the tone when volume is muted. Any chance that's what you're experiencing? The functionality of receiving the gesture is still there.